# create a bitmap with a bitmap inside

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas, bitmapfactory

I know - the title may sounds strange. Let me explain:

I created an image to show you, what I'm talking about:
[image: the problem]

I got an image (Bitmap (1)), that as the size of 150w/200h.

Now I need to make the bitmap bigger ((2) 400w/400h), but the original image must have the same size. So that the image is embedded in white background.

I think one way to solve it is this:
* create a big bitmap
* create a canvas for it
* draw the original bitmap on the canvas
* draw the canvas
* generate a bitmap of the canvas

The problem for me is, that it must be done in a background thread without drawing a view.
I hope you understand me.

Comment: Then spawn a Thread instance and do it there... What's the question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the code bellow to achive it. Where `smallBitmap` is your original image and `bigBitmap` is the final image:

```
Bitmap bigBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height , Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
canvas = new Canvas(bigBitmap);
canvas.drawBitmap(smallBitmap, left, top, new Paint());
```

Regards.

Comment: At least I need a bitmap. Here I got a canvas.

Comment: And you have a `BitMap`. The `Canvas` is a tool used to draw to the `bigBitmap`. After running the code above the `bigBitmap` have your small bitmap drawn inside it.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

1. Create a thread and in that thread object:
2. Create a new bitmap.
3. Create a canvas based on that bitmap.
4. Draw your bitmap to that canvas

and voila!

I hope this helps.